Blazor @onchange event doesn't fire
In the Blazor web assembly application, the @onchange event attached to the <select> element fails to trigger when selecting the "Weather" option.
The goal is to dynamically render components based on the selected option, but the event doesn't respond as expected.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<h2>Dynamic Component</h2>

<select @onchange="ChangeValue"> /* doesn't fire */
    <option value="Default">select</option>
    <option value="Weather">Weather</option>
</select>

@if(selectedType is not null)
{
    <div class="p-2 mt-2">
        <DynamicComponent Type="selectedType"/>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h3>Waiting...</h3>
}
                    
@code {
    private Type? selectedType;

    private Dictionary<String, Type> components = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {

            ["Weather"] = typeof(Weather)
    };
    

    public void ChangeValue(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("entre");

        if (e.Value is String DropdownValue)
        {
            selectedType = components[DropdownValue];
        }
        else
        {
            selectedType = null;
        }
    }
}


Prove that it's a Wasm app and not a Blazor Web App.  Post Program.cs. Because the event should have fired.

There is something you're not showing us.  This is the result, in Net8, WebAssembly Interactivity set at Global location, when pasting your code into Home.

